# In SQLServer 2012 how can i SELECT from a view when access to underlying table is ecplicitly DENYied

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, permission-denied

I have a table on which I had to DENY SELECTs to some users (REVOKE didn't work as all the SELECTs were GRANTed at DB level).

However, to these users, I want to give SELECT permissions on a VIEW which SELECTs from this table.

On reading about permissions in SQLServer I have found that one cannot override a DENY.

Is there any another way to achieve this?

Comment: If the owner of the view is the same as the owner of the table then selecting through a view will work fine, Permissions won't even be checked on the table.

Comment: yeah, that's true, but it's not the case here.

Comment: @ShivamTiwari, you mean the objects/schemas have different owners? An unbroken ownership chain is the only way I know of to allow selects from the view when the referenced objects have missing grants or explicit deny.

Answer (score 0):

The only way with the following rights to enable reading the view would be to have the same owner of the View and the Table.

If you can't do it, you will have to give the rights to the table explicitely, or review the ENTIRE rights mapping.